# Group two lists by a common user id linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists

Albums and Photos

I would like to combine them so that each album will contain all the photos assigned to that album and return only the albums for a defined user id

```
class Album{
 Id
 UserId
}

class Photo{
 Id
 AlbumId

}


    albums.Add(new Album { Id = 1, Photos = null, Title = "Summer", UserId = 1 });
    albums.Add(new Album { Id = 2, Photos = null, Title = "Winter", UserId = 1 });
    albums.Add(new Album { Id = 3, Photos = null, Title = "Spring", UserId = 2 });
```

I have tried following but this returns all albums, what am I missing?

```
  var result = (from album in albums
                          join photo in photos on album.Id equals photo.AlbumId
                          where album.UserId == 1
                          select new Album
                          {
                              Id = album.Id,
                              Title = album.Title,
                              UserId = album.UserId,
                              Photos = photos.Where(p => p.AlbumId == album.Id)
                          }).ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Typo perhaps? What is the purpose of the "where album.UserId == userId"? That would filter it down to a single user id. Edit: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: For user 1 i expect to see album 1, and album 2 but I also get album 3 ( which is assigned to user id 2)

Comment: Ahh gotcha, your edit helps.

Comment: Hm, when I throw something together and test your query I'm getting the expected result of 2 albums, ids 1 and 2.

Comment: That's weird... hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var groupedAlbums = albums
    .GroupJoin(photos,
        a => a.Id,
        p => p.AlbumId,
        (a, p) => new
        {
            AlbumId = a.Id,
            UserId = a.UserId,
            Title = a.Title,
            Photos = p.Select(pp => pp).ToList()
        })
        .Where(a => a.Photos.Any())
        .Where(a => a.UserId == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of simplicity so unless I am missing something obvious,

```
        var here = albums.Where(a => a.UserId == 1).Select(b => new Album
            {
                Id = b.Id,
                Title = b.Title,
                UserId = b.UserId,
                Photos = photos.Where(a => a.AlbumId == b.Id).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your input, agreed simple is always preferred